# Can Wordpress show posts based on a button that the user clicked 2 pages back?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories, filters, tags

For a new website, I need to show posts based on age category (Adult or Kids), this input should be remembered until the user arrives on specific page a few clicks later, input can also be changed on the specific page, which shows the post type of the other age category.

The flow goes likes this:

1. User arrives on the homepage and decides to seek help.
2. User arrives on a page thats ask him if he is an adult or a kid. He chooses Adult.
3. He can see relevant questions about his mental health and decides to click on a question.
4. He arrives on the page of his question and has to see all posts that are relevant to the Adult button he pressed in step 2. He cannot see the posts for Kids until he decides to change the filter button at the top of the page.

I've scoured the internet for a possible solution for my problem but i've not been able to put this problem into words.

Would anyone be so kind to please help me find a workable solution to my problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

1. Use a session.
   Set a session and update your session value each time the filter has changed by the user.
   Check out [PHP sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).
2. Use a cookie.
   Set a cookie and update your cookie value each time the filter has changed by the user.
   Check out [PHP setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).
3. Update user_meta (if users are registered users).
   When your users are registered users, you can set and update a `user_meta` value each time the user changes the filter.
   Check out [add_user_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_meta/) and [update_user_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/).

Comment: For completeness' sake, you could also append values to/route based on parameters in the URL. But I think cookies would be the most elegant & efficient

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your input. Would there be any links/docs recommended for this kind of approach? I mostly work with Wordpress and Elementor. I do not have to most knowledge on custom coding in the CMS.

If not, I will do more research on how to create this myself. Thank you!

Comment: This StackExchange is for custom coding. You will have to check the Elementor documentation or contact their support as this is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Tjorven Dewulf I think that you need to create a form or one solution which show the post using a filter. If I'm right you will need to create wp_query regarding your filter and if the filter changes the post will be changed.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer, I do not completely follow. Would you be so kind and explain it a bit more in depth please?